# SF1 VF Mobile view

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I am attempting to create a mobile view for SF1, pretty simple nothing crazy.  The issue I'm having is that I cannot get it to scroll when I'm viewing it in SF1.  I have tried just about every option and I am at a loss of what to do/try.

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardController="Contact" extensions="MobileContactPrefrences" showHeader="false" action="{!init}"   sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="true"  >
    <apex:outputPanel>   
    <div class = "scroll">
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
         <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
            <td colspan="2">Member Likes</td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
        </tr>       
        <apex:repeat value="{!contactLikes}" var="l">
            <tr>
                <td>{!l['Name']}</td>
                <td>{!l['Notes__c']}</td>
            </tr>               
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
            <td colspan="2">Member Dislikes</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
        </tr>            
        <apex:repeat value="{!contactDislikes}" var="d">
            <tr>
                <td>{!d['Name']}</td>
                <td>{!d['Notes__c']}</td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
  </div>
  </apex:outputPanel>
```

This is what it looks like on my mobile, The list should begin to scroll.
[image: Mobile View]

This is what the view looks like on the actual Contact page layout.
[image: Desktop View]

Comment: Try setting `showHeader="false"`.

Comment: Updated with my current page settings

Comment: Mobile doesn't show scrollbars. Can you drag it up and down?

Comment: You shouldn't use pageBlock and pageBlockTable in a VF Page which is going to be viewed on a mobile as stated here in the [Salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/vf_dev_best_practices_components_to_avoid.htm)
Why don't you just build a simple table with an apex:repeat ?

Comment: @JulienGaïotto Updated my code, I think I might be boned.. still no scroll bar

Comment: Can you try to set standardStylesheets to false, and add that meta tag             <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> ?